# Is Prolog an untyped language? What's the difference between Prolog and dynamically typed languages?

Tags: programming-languages, types, lisp, prolog, dynamic-typing

If Prolog has clear distinction between strings, numbers, atoms, lists and compound structures how can it be called untyped.
And how does it differ from dynamically typed languages like Lisp for example.

Which part of the definition of "dynamically typed language" does Prolog conflict with? And which part of the definition of "untyped language" does Lisp conflict with?

Any insight is appreciated.

**Update**

I already know what's the difference between dynamic, static, strong and weak typing. My question is about a special case which is Prolog. I just want to understand how is Prolog considered to be untyped though it doesn't seem to have a clear difference from dynamically typed languages.

Here's *a* reference that Prolog is untyped
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Types

Comment: do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I thing you are mixing up strong typing and dynamic typing.

Comment: a reference for what exactly ?

Comment: A reference for someone calling Prolog an "untyped language" would be helpful.  The opposite of dynamic typing is not "untyped" but static typing, i.e. types for variables determined at compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prolog is mostly untyped in the sense that you can pass any kind of term to any predicate and, usually, the worst case is that the predicate will not succeed. However, arithmetic predicates, such as `is` and `=:=` expect numeric arguments and may blow up - so there is a notion of types there.

Non-pure predicates might also expect objects of type "file handle" and blow up otherwise.

So, calling Prolog "untyped" is not strictly true.

Answer (score 1):

When you write a predicate like

```
head([H|_], H).
```

you don't specify any types anywhere. You can call `head([1,2,3], X)`, you can call `head("foo", X)` and you can even call `head(1, [1,2,3])`. All of them run just fine. The last one won't cause any error, it will just return `false.`. I think that's what was meant by “untyped”.

Comment: +1 nice example...But does the fact that it returns false instead of issuing an error enough to call it "untyped" ?

Comment: @is7s, I think it does. If you try to call `head(1)` it causes an error, because it has wrong argument count, it does not return `false`. `false` is part of normal function of the language, not some error state.

Comment: @svick Actually the example you just gave shows that prolog has types, since it shows that the type of `head` is a predicate which expects one argument, if it was really untyped it should have returned false in this case as well. Furthermore, the main example in your post also can be read as "`head` is a predicate which expects a first argument of _type_ list, and it is undefined (`false`) if the first argument is anything not of the _type_ list.

Comment: I'm quite convinced that Prolog is not strictly untyped as Nick said, I guess it's somewhere between _dynamically_ _typed_ and _untyped_. It can be called _partially_ _typed_

Comment: @is7s, reading `false` as undefined is wrong. The built-in predicate `member` returns `false` when you give it an item and a list that doesn't contain it. Would you say that `member` is undefined is the second argument doesn't contain the first argument?

Comment: @svick well to be more precise I would read it as _maybe_ _undefined_ since under a closed-world assumption anything undefined is assumed to be *false* :)

Comment: The predicate false/0 and the display of false is SWI prolog specific. The normal predicate in other Prolog systems to cause a failure is fail/0 and other Prolog systems normally display No when the given query fails.